# Implement states in functional programming

Tags: functional-programming

I'm currently writing an Android music player application using Scala. I chose Scala for its functional programming capabilities and I want to make the code the most FP compliant possible.

As FP implies immutability, the code should not carry any state and variables should be immutable. But I'm facing some complicate use cases I don't know how to resolve in a pure functional programming way.

The first one is the playlist case. The music player is reading a song in the middle of a playlist. This can be represented with a list of songs and a cursor that indicates the current played song. But when that song ends, then the player has to play the next one, hence, change the value of the cursor.

The same problem happens with the playlist itself: the user must be able to change (add or suppress songs) the playlist. If the playlist itself is immutable, any time the user adds or suppress a song, a new playlist is produced. But that playlist must be affected to a variable that must then be mutable.

Everywhere I look in this application, I see states — is the player paused or not? What is the current song, the current playlist? What is the current state of the settings? Etc. — and I don't know how to solve this in a pure functional programming way, *i.e.* with immutable variables.

As these use cases seem pretty standard, I suppose there are design patterns to solve them (like monads) but I don't know where to look.

Comment: http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html

Comment: "FP compliant" – there is no such thing

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some libraries that tried to address this, the result was fairly ugly, IMO.

Basically, turned Activity, Fragment, etc. into pure functions that accepted State and returned State.

This in conjunction with IO monads made the interface somewhat pure. An example of this follows (the source to PureActivity can be found at https://github.com/pfn/iota-pure), the 'state' in this case is 'Option[Process]' with Process being present when logcat is running and empty when it is not. No vars:

```
class LogcatActivity extends AppCompatActivity with PureActivity[Option[Process]] {
  val LOG_LINE = """^([A-Z])/(.+?)\( *(\d+)\): (.*?)$""".r
  val buffersize = 1024
  lazy val toolbar = newToolbar
  lazy val recycler = {
    val r = new RecyclerView(this)
    r.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this))
    r.setAdapter(Adapter)
    r
  }
  lazy val layout = l[LinearLayout](
    toolbar.!  >>= lp(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT),
    recycler.! >>= lp(MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1)
  ) >>= vertical

  override def initialState(b: Option[Bundle]) = None

  override def applyState[T](s: ActivityState[T]) = s match {
    case OnPreCreate(_) => s(IO(
      setTheme(if (Settings.get(Settings.DAYNIGHT_MODE)) R.style.SetupTheme_Light else R.style.SetupTheme_Dark)
    ))
    case OnCreate(_) => s(IO {
      toolbar.setTitle("Logcat")
      toolbar.setNavigationIcon(resolveAttr(R.attr.qicrCloseIcon, _.resourceId))
      toolbar.navigationOnClick0(finish())
      setContentView(layout.perform())
    })
    case OnStart(_) => s.applyState(IO {
      var buffering = true
      val logcat = "logcat" :: "-v" :: "brief" :: Nil
      val lineLogger = new ProcessLogger {
        override def out(s: => String) = addLine(s)
        override def buffer[X](f: => X) = f
        override def err(s: => String) = addLine(s)

        def addLine(line: String) = line match {
          case LOG_LINE(level, tag, pid, msg) =>
            if (tag != "ResourceType") UiBus.run {
              val c = Adapter.getItemCount // store in case at max items already
              Adapter.buffer += LogEntry(tag, level, msg)
              Adapter.notifyItemInserted(math.min(buffersize, c + 1))
              if (!buffering)
                recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(Adapter.getItemCount)
            }
          case _ =>
        }
      }
      Future {
        Thread.sleep(500)
        buffering = false
      } onSuccessMain { case _ =>
        recycler.scrollToPosition(Adapter.getItemCount - 1)
      }
      logcat.run(lineLogger).?
    })
    case OnStop(proc) => s.applyState(IO {
      proc.foreach(_.destroy())
      None
    })
    case x => defaultApplyState(x)
  }

  case class LogEntry(tag: String, level: String, msg: String)
  case class LogcatHolder(view: TextView) extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    def bind(e: LogEntry): Unit = view.setText(" %1 %2: %3" formatSpans (
      textColor(MessageAdapter.nickColor(e.level), e.level),
      textColor(MessageAdapter.nickColor(e.tag),   e.tag), e.msg))
  }
  object Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter[LogcatHolder] {
    val buffer = RingBuffer[LogEntry](buffersize)
    override def getItemCount = buffer.size
    override def onBindViewHolder(vh: LogcatHolder, i: Int) = vh.bind(buffer(i))

    override def onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int) = {
      val tv = new TextView(LogcatActivity.this)
      tv.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE)
      LogcatHolder(tv)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this also highlights poorly in intellij due to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-3170

Comment: Very interresting answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the UI. It is stateful in its essence. You cannot and must not work with it without states. There is only one correct way: to divide the code without states from the code with states.

The best concept for that is the FRP - [Functional reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming). It separates functional parts and immutable boxes with mutable stateful content and connects them by events.

Be careful, many so-named reactive programming technologies on the net **are not such** really and only declare being reactive. For example, java RX is absolute invalid and lacks two **very** important features. (hiding listeners and simultaneousity support)

There is a very good [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1633430103) on the subject. It can be found on the net in some actions, too. The authors give opensource base library and swift FRP support library that could be used as a pattern for creation of your own FRP classes for your need.